# What is the meaning of "No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line xxx"?

Tags: fonts

After pdflatex compilation of `somefile.tex`, the log file `somefile.log` is full of the following message: "No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line xxx", where the line number xxx is sometimes repeated. What is the meaning of this log entry? What steps should I take in response?

Comment: Related Follow-up Question: [How to surpress flood of LateX Infos "No math alphabet change to frozen version normal", especially when using tensor package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/657395/4301).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an informative message that you can ignore, it relates to a new feature added last year to allow more math alphabets to be used.

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Freeze math alphabet allocation in version normal.
(Font)              Allocated math groups: 14 (local: 2) on input line 17.
```

Previously, if using math alphabets (which are dynamically allocated on demand) caused more than 16 math fonts (including pre-allocated math symbol fonts) in a document you would get a non-recoverable error. Now if you get within a user-setable count of that limit the math font allocation is undone and reverts to a frozen version leaving space for new allocations in later formula.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amssymb,euscript,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\matha{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathb{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathc{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\typeout{A===}

$\mathit{x} \mathrm{x} \mathtt{x} \mathcal{x} \mathbf{x} \EuScript{X} \mathscr{X}
\matha{a}
\mathb{a}
\mathc{a}
$

\typeout{B===}

$x$

\typeout{C===}

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
A===
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 15.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 15.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 15
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+eus on input line 15.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/ueus.fd
File: ueus.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 Euler Script
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Freeze math alphabet allocation in version normal.
(Font)              Allocated math groups: 14 (local: 2) on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
ne 19.

B===
LaTeX Font Info:    No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input l
ine 23.
C===
```

So after the first it logs that you have got within 2 of the limit

But the next formula didn't make any new allocations so a full re-set isn't needed so it short-circuits and logs:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input l
ine 23.
```

If `$x` is changed to `$\mathc{x}$` or anything else requiring further math font allocation, the message changes to

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
ne 23.
```

Comment: I have a longish file (>= 250) pages which causes 19417 messages of these in the log file. I'm filtering the output of the pdflatex run output, but the log is more or less unusable… Can one turn this off? I think this has to be taking a non-negliglible time during compilation, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I doubt it changes the time but `\def\@font@info#1{}` will silence it or `\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}` disables the mechanism, but then as in older releases you may run out of fonts and not be able to process the document at all

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Please see the related Follow-up Question: [How to surpress flood of LateX Infos "No math alphabet change to frozen version normal", especially when using tensor package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/657395).

Comment: So under what circumstances is the error now triggered? If you don't reserve sufficient local alphabets for the number of additions within a group? Or?

Comment: @cfr previously you got an error if more than 16 mathfam were used in a document, now you get an error if after the first 16-localmathalphabets mathfam have been allocated you don't use more than localmathalphabets extra mathfam in each formua so for example even if localmathalphabets is as low as 1 you could have a document that declared 26 different \mathbba, ...\mathbbz fonts and demonstrated them all in the same document as long as you didn't use them in the same formula

Comment: Why do you give so much care to an old non-Unicode TeX engine?

Comment: @wipet because it's used by something like 90% of tex users. arXiv for example doesn't accept luatex files (unless you hide that they are tex) we live in the world we live in, not the world we choose.

Comment: It is usual that very old versions is no more supported by maintainers of various software. Then users (and maintainers of arXiv, for example) **must** to change to newer software. Supporting 30 years old software (pdftex engine) today is the road to the hell. Simply: remove pdftex from the TeX live distribution and don't maintain such macros like mentioned here.

Comment: @wipet you have no existing users to lose, so it's easier for you to make optex unicode only.

Comment: Even if I set the counter to 4 (or 12), I can still get the error with `$\mathsf{}\mathit{}\mathbf{}$` (or whatever it was in that other question) if I make it so enough get defined in the preamble, so there's something I'm not getting. (So nothing new.)

Comment: @cfr no setting will guarantee you don't get the error, if you try to use 17 fonts in a single math expression or declare 17 symbol fonts (as opposed to math alphabets) then you will run out of slots. but codeless comments on a 2 year old answer aren't the best way to discuss specific instances of the error