# How to surpress flood of LateX Infos "No math alphabet change to frozen version normal", especially when using tensor package?

Tags: math-fonts, logging, tensor

In actuarial documents we use much mathematically oriented notation, for which we need many math fonts. In
[What is the meaning of "No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line xxx"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655563/what-is-the-meaning-of-no-math-alphabet-change-to-frozen-version-normal-on-inpu)
David Carlisle explains that a new LaTeX feature produces Info messages when a certain number of fonts is loaded.
We reach this limit in most of our documents and in fact some of them produce log files in the range of 100MB which cannot be parsed be TeXstudio.
a) Is there any way to shut off the Infos?
b) Can this be done on the admin level (for all users)?
c) Is there anything that can be done about the Infos produced by the use of the tensor package specifically?

The follwing minimal example shows that each use of \tensor produces more than 20 messages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsfonts}                       % load a range of math fonts
\RequirePackage{mathcomp}
\RequirePackage{MnSymbol}

\RequirePackage{tensor}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

                                                % reach limit of 14 fonts
$\mathcal{X}$                                   % same result:      \ensuremath{\mathcal{X}}

$\mathtt{X}$                                    % same result       \ensuremath{\mathtt{X}}

$\mathbf{X}$                                    % same result       \ensuremath{\mathbf{X}}

$\mathsf{X}$                                    % same result       \ensuremath{\mathsf{X}}


                                                % each line produces 1 LaTeX Info
$X$                                             % same result       \ensuremath{X}

                                                % each line produces one LaTeX Info
$\tensor*{\mathsf{X}}{}$                        % same result       \ensuremath{\tensor*{\mathsf{X}}{}}

                                                % each line produces more than 20 LaTeX Infos
$\tensor*[_{}^{}]{\mathsf{X}}{_{}^{}}$          % same result       \ensuremath{\tensor*[_{}^{}]{\mathsf{X}}{_{}^{}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well they all use `\@font@info`, so if you would shut them up you would shut up also all other font messages.

Comment: as Ulrike says you could silence the message, but do you need to load so many fonts? you load amsfonts but then you mak almost all of them inaccessible by loadng mnsymbol

Comment: We surely do not need all of them in every document, but with have many colleagues with little LaTeX knowledge who have to work with it.
That fore we have created a setting with a central package that is adequate for most documents and uses many fonts.
I could try to find out if some of the fonts could be omitted, but still the problem would occur in cases where somebody load 1-2 fonts more.

Comment: A will try removing amsfonts from our internal packages and see what happens. However I will also keep the counter localmathalphabets Frank Mittelbach mentioned in mind.