# Why does \tensor produce errors when LaTeX Info warns about number of math fonts?

Tags: compilation-error, math-fonts, latex-base, tensor

In actuarial documents we use much mathematically oriented notation, for which we need many math fonts. In
[What is the meaning of "No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line xxx"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655563/what-is-the-meaning-of-no-math-alphabet-change-to-frozen-version-normal-on-inpu)
David Carlisle explains that a new LaTeX feature produces Info messages when a certain number of fonts is loaded.
We observe a problem with the use of the tensor package. When the number of different math fonts reaches the warning limit (14) during the usage of \tensor, 6 LaTeX errors are thrown and the contents of the makro are typeset 3 times.
a) Is this a problem in the LaTeX core or in tensor?
b) Is there a way to circumvent the problem until it is fixed?

The following minimal example shows that \tensor produces errors und unexpected results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsfonts}                       % load a range of math fonts
\RequirePackage{mathcomp}
\RequirePackage{MnSymbol}

\RequirePackage{tensor}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

                                                % approach limit of 14 fonts
$\mathcal{X}$                                   % same result:      \ensuremath{\mathcal{X}}

$\mathtt{X}$                                    % same result       \ensuremath{\mathtt{X}}

$\mathbf{X}$                                    % same result       \ensuremath{\mathbf{X}}


                                                % the following lines typesets X 3 times and produces 6 LaTeX errors
$\tensor*{\mathsf{X}}{}$                        % same result       \ensuremath{\tensor*{\mathsf{X}}{}}
                                                % the following line would produce the same error
% $\tensor*[_{}^{}]{\mathsf{X}}{_{}^{}}$        % same result       \ensuremath{\tensor*[_{}^{}]{\mathsf{X}}{_{}^{}}}
                                                % the following line would produce no error
% $\mathsf{X}$                                  % same result       \ensuremath{\mathsf{X}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could remove amsfonts

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be loading amsfonts as they are mostly hidden by mnsymbol, but it is enough to ensure thè first use of `\mathsf` is not in `\tensor`(even if that use is in a discarded box, as here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsfonts}                       % load a range of math fonts
\RequirePackage{mathcomp}
\RequirePackage{MnSymbol}

\RequirePackage{tensor}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

                                                % approach limit of 14 fonts
$\mathcal{X}$                                   % same result:      \ensuremath{\mathcal{X}}

$\mathtt{X}$                                    % same result       \ensuremath{\mathtt{X}}

$\mathbf{X}$                                    % same result       \ensuremath{\mathbf{X}}

\sbox0{$\mathsf{X}$}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                                                % the following lines typesets X 3 times and produces 6 LaTeX errors
$\tensor*{\mathsf{X}}{}$                        % same result       \ensuremath{\tensor*{\mathsf{X}}{}}
                                                % the following line would produce the same error
% $\tensor*[_{}^{}]{\mathsf{X}}{_{}^{}}$        % same result       \ensuremath{\tensor*[_{}^{}]{\mathsf{X}}{_{}^{}}}
                                                % the following line would produce no error
% $\mathsf{X}$                                  % same result       \ensuremath{\mathsf{X}}

\end{document}
```

A simpler package-free example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters1}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters2}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters3}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters4}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters5}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters6}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters7}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters8}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters9}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}

\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersa}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

%$\mathsf{X}$

$\mathchoice{\mathsf{X}}{\mathsf{X}}{\mathsf{X}}{\mathsf{X}}$
                     

\end{document}
```

which gives the same error. Not declaring `lettersa` or using `\mathsf` before `\mathchoice` avoids the error.  We may be able to catch this case..

Comment: For the moment using \setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0} should keep you going, if you then hit the limit it is the hard limit of TeX . But as David said we should be able to do something eventually and I opened an issue at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/921 for it

Comment: I'm a bit overwhelmed by the speed of your reactions and I thank you both!
I will try the counter localmathalphabets to avoid the overflowing logs and I will also try removing amsfonts from our internal packages, in order to figure out if any of our important documents gets affected by the omission.
In case amsfonts are needed somewhere I still can fall back to discarding a few boxes at the beginning of the document.