# Dog bites man as news, or the verbosity of the messages for no changes to math alphabets

Tags: math-fonts, bugs

I have a certain LaTeX project that results in a 250 page PDF file whose log file is filled with «No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line blah» messages. In fact, the file is such that

```
syzygy:carcajes mariano$ grep -c 'No math alphabet' temas.log 
19958
```

I asked the other day about this in a comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655619/525) about this and it seems this is related to some update allowing us to use more math alphabets, which is always good.

I would classify this as a usability bug. Maybe a little bit more parsimony would not hurt?

There are often several messages per line:

```
syzygy:carcajes mariano$ grep ^ine temas.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 1
 159 ine 1956.
```

This count is not very precise, as it may be accumulating the messages from line 1956 in the several .tex files that comprise the run, but these are only twelve files.

Comment: `\def\@font@info#1{}` ?

Comment: you have tagged this as a bug, but if you think it's a bug (or in this case a feature request) you should open an issue at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues not here

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{aa}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bb}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cc}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{dd}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\usepackage{amsfonts,bm}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ee}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ff}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathit{A}$
$\mathsf{A}$
$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathit{A}$
$\mathbf{A}$
$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathit{A}$
$\mathtt{A}$

$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathit{A}$
$\mathsf{A}$
$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathit{A}$
$\mathbf{A}$
$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathit{A}$
$\mathtt{A}$
$\mathtt{A}$
$\mathtt{A}$
$\mathtt{A}$
$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$
$\mathcal{A}\mathbb{A}\mathrm{A}\mathtt{A}$

\end{document}
```

Produces from `grep 'math alphabet' file.log`

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 149.
LaTeX Font Info:    Freeze math alphabet allocation in version normal.
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input l
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input l
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
```

You could disable the new mechanism by adding to the preamble

```
\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}
```

But then you get

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15 $\mathit{A}
                $
?
```

which is why the new mechanism was added..

However the default value is 2 so you could try setting it to 1 or 0 to see if your document works without local allocation.

If not you could instead add

```
\makeatletter
\def\@font@info#1{}
\makeatother
```

to silence font info messages, the above search would then show no hits.

This might be thought a bit agressive so a third possibility would be

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@font@info\@font@info
\def\@font@info#1{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname\detokenize{#1}\endcsname\relax
  \old@font@info{#1}%
\fi
\expandafter\xdef\csname\detokenize{#1}\endcsname{}%
}
\makeatother
```

This arranges that each font info message is only issued once, so produces

```
$ grep 'math alphabet' file.log 
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 149.
LaTeX Font Info:    Freeze math alphabet allocation in version normal.
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input li
LaTeX Font Info:    No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input l
```

Answer (score 0):

[David Carlisle demonstrates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663843) how to either disable all LaTeX Font Info or to
"arranges that each font info message is only issued once". As third alternative just the "No math alphabet change to frozen version"-messages can be suppressed by:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\def\@font@info#1{%
\IfBeginWith{#1}{No math alphabet change to frozen version}{\relax}{%
\GenericInfo{(Font)\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\space\space}%
{LaTeX Font Info: \space\space\space#1}%
}%
}%
\makeatother
```