# babel+newtx+superiours+stmaryrd+LS1+LS2+biblatex+biber+\cite+\mathsf+\mathit+\mathbf+\printbibliography = swallowed space after math mode

Tags: math-mode, biber, babel, white-space, newtx

Running `pdflatex`+`biber` in a loop till stabilization on

```latex
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% only to omit the page number
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{superiors}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixsymbols2}{LS1}{stixfrak}{m}{n}% for \typecolon ⦂ (U+2982)
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixletters}{LS1}{stix}{m}{it}% for \nvDash ⊭ (U+22AD)
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{B,
    author={M. B.},
    title={Title},
    langid={USenglish}}
@online{W,
    author={Eric Wolfgang Weisstein},
    title={5-smooth numbers, i.e., numbers whose prime divisors are all $\le$ 5}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}% for white parens, braces with vertical bar, curved angle brackets, wiggly fences, double wiggly fences, pullback, pushout.
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
\cite{B,W}
$\mathsf{}\mathit{}\mathbf{}$
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output]

Bug: the space in `$\le$ 5` in the input is swallowed in the output: `≤5`.

The issue seems to be independent on whether you use `$…$` or `\(…\)` as math delimiters. The issue does depend on the compiler: with `lualatex` or `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`, the bug vanishes.

The example is minimal in the sense that dropping any line except `\pagestyle{empty}` leads to compilation errors or does not expose the bug. For the purpose of keeping the example small, lots of meaningful contents (taking some symbols from *STIX*, typesetting math letters in sans, italics, and bold, and certain bibliographic data) has been dropped.

Current versions, with which the bug occurs:

- pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
- article 2023/05/17 v1.4n
- babel 2024/02/07 v24.2
- USenglish 2017/06/06 v3.3
- newtx 2024/02/24 v1.739
- superiors 2024/01/07 - 2.0superiors
- stmaryrd 1994/03/03
- ls1stix.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex
- ls2stix.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex
- biblatex 2023/03/05 v3.19
- biber 2.19

On a slightly older stock Debian TeX Live distribution, the bug does NOT occur; the versions are as follows:

- pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian)
- article 2023/05/17 v1.4n
- babel 2023/09/29 v3.95
- USenglish 2017/06/06 v3.3r
- newtx 2023/08/20 v1.724
- superiors 2019/08/18 - 1.06
- stmaryrd 1994/03/03
- ls1stix.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex
- ls2stix.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex
- biblatex 2023/03/05 v3.19
- biber 2.19

Whom to blame and ask for a bugfix? Although the maintainers of TeX Live, newtx, and babel would be the natural suspects, you never know (as the bug might have always been there and might have got unmasked just now due to changes elsewhere) …

UPDATE (2024-03-24): As of biblatex 3.20 and biber 2.20, the space appeared, so the bug is gone at least for now.

Comment: Possibly related to the changes which make this code compile without error despite the number of maths fonts used? See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655619/? Maybe? (Maybe not?)

Comment: Not a direct solution to the problem at hand, but a good work-around: change `are all $\le$ 5` to `are all $\le 5$` and recompile. Aside: Since the math formula consists of *both* `\le` and `5`, rendering only `\le` but not `5` as well in math mode is actually questionable practice. While you're at it, you may (should, really) also want to change `5-smooth` to `$5$-smooth`, since "5" is a (very minimalistic) math formula. Observe that with these changes in place, both instances of "5" will be rendered in math-upright mode instead of in text-italic mode.

Comment: @Mico Another trivial workaround is `$\le$\ 5`. As for the title, it is taken from http://oeis.org/A051037. Strictly speaking, we were to typeset `${<}{=}$ 5` anyway. The typesetting issue is independent thereof; we get the same problem (space swallowed) if we replace `$\le$ 5` with `$math$ text`.

Comment: @cfr Not impossible. In the log, I see “Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input line 27.”, “No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line 28.”, and “593399 words of font info for 91 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000” but NO warnings, errors, failures, or reports of missing stuff.

Comment: adding `\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}` works around the issue but I'm not sure where the space went will look later

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My current workaround is skipping using `superiors`, which results in uglier superscripts for footnote marks but is fine otherwise. As for `\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}`, where to put it? Please do look where the space went.

Comment: you would set the counter in the document preamble but the definition in my answer fixed the issue rather than avoid the symptoms

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`babel` uses a definition equivalent to `\ingnorespacesafterend` to ignore spaces after `\end{otherlanguage}` but if someone (or some package) calls `\endotherlanguage` directly the ignore flag is set globally true for the rest of the document potentially.

(first version, not quite right)

```
\def\endotherlanguage{\ignorespaces}
```

The definition can be modified to just use `\ignorespaces` if it is not used as an environment.

```
\makeatletter
\def\endotherlanguage{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\otherlanguage@env\ignorespacesafterend\fi
  \ignorespaces}
\def\otherlanguage@env{otherlanguage}
\makeatother
```

which can be placed in the preamble (anywhere after `babel` has been loaded)

The original Babel definition is

```
\long\def\endotherlanguage{%
  \global\@ignoretrue\ignorespaces}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was about to report it, but you came first with http://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/288  . Appending `\def\endotherlanguage{\ignorespaces}` to the end of the preamble resolves the issue at least for the minimal example at hand. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlMa1r this answer is wrong. sorry, and update coming  up once I work out what it should be

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know! Do you imply that `\def\endotherlanguage{\ignorespaces}` introduces issues on other inputs (not the one in the original post)?

Comment: @AlMa1r yes exactly: it was too simple it fixed some cases that were broken and broke some cases that were fixed. I just updated with an ifx that hopefully does the right thing in both cases.

Comment: Testing done. Your fix works great on my input of around 480 pages for both pdflatex (the output was broken before) and lualatex (the output was not broken before). Thanks a lot!